# Test if page returns .pdf

Tags: pdf, testing, robotframework

Is there any way I can test if the web page returns a PDF correctly?
I have a web page that generates a PDF, and after pressing button the "GET PDF" it opens up a new tab in chrome and I need to know if it is a PDF.

I think I need to get `Сontent-Type` header  but I don't know how, as it opens new tab within the browser.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you can get the url from 'GET PDF' button, if so use the below code and pass that URL

This code uses RequestsLibrary

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Collections
Library           RequestsLibrary 

*** Test Cases ***
Test Request content-type
    create ntlm session    github    http://example.com    auth=${names}
    ${resp}=    Get Request    github    /files/diversification.pdf
    log    ${resp.headers['content-type']}
```

Another option is given below. I am not sure if this is a reliable one. It works for me. Find the pdf object  xpath and get Type attribute.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
Test Request content-type

      Open Browser    http://example.com/files/diversification.pdf    ${BROWSER}
      ${ContentType}=    Get Element Attribute    xpath=//*[@id="plugin"]@type
```

Comment: I don't have the URL of page with pdf cause it is generated. I click generate PDF button and then it opens new tab with `url/gdf65gfd2g2fg5vcb2c2b` (example).